# Fact and Dimension Tables: One-to-One Relationship

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I'm trying to develop a suitable BI solution whereby the dimension and fact tables have a 1:1 relationship.

Take, for example, the following:

**Fact_UserData**

- *User ID*
- *Location ID*
- *Occupation ID*
- a bunch of numeric data that can be meaningfully aggregated

**Dim_User**

- *User ID*
- Gender
- Ethnicity

**Dim_Location**

- *Location ID*
- District
- City
- State

**Dim_Occupation**

- *Occupation ID*
- Occupation Name

In this example, assume that Fact_UserData and Dim_User will always have a 1:1 relationship via User ID.

What's primarily throwing me off is the 1:1 relationship - should I have a dedicated User dimension or should I merge those attributes into the fact table? I'm hesitant to merge since, according to [Kimball](http://www.kimballgroup.com/html/PDFs/Fables_Facts.pdf), degenerate dimensions should be reserved for operational control numbers. I'm also wondering whether it makes sense to have occupation as a dedicated dimension - grouping by occupation is crucial from the perspective of the business, which is why I initially have it as its own dimension.

As a generalization to the occupation dimension question, what would be the best-practice approach to handling situations where dimensions only have two fields: ID and name? (Think of it like a typical Customers dimension, expect that it only has the fields Customer ID and Customer Name.) Assume that the dimension has 10+ entries and doesn't have any hierarchies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, considering that a person can change occupation and location, I would expect a `DateKey` in that fact table too. If you pull  occupation and/or location into user dimension, you'll end up with type-2 dimension, so will have to track temporal changes there.
There is nothing wrong with having dimension just with `Key, BusinessKey` -- things change over time, you will eventually add something.

Comment: Agreed - It looks like this fact table is just a periodic snapshot of a user's occupation and location (with the period being "forever"), with the grain defined as one row per User ID. There's nothing wrong with this, but I think that a DateKey should also exist on the fact.

Comment: Thanks Damir and @West for the input. I realize my example doesn't exactly reflect my actual business model (I can't explicitly state it for security reasons). Specifically, 'location' and 'occupation' would actually be fixed for a given user - it will never change. And there would never be any duplicate users in either the fact table or user dimension table. Would my model still hold?

Comment: Last question to follow up: Since every occupation entry in the Occupation dimension is unique, would I need a dedicated dimension for it or should I just include 'Occupation Name' as an attribute in the fact table instead? As mentioned in my post, I do need grouping by occupation.

Comment: Your preference; will work both ways. If separate dimension, you can `select occupation, sum(...) from fact_tbl group by occupation` without having to join `user` table -- which may or may not be faster, depending on size of `user` table.